# Unable to install .NET Framework 4.5.2

Tags: .net, .net-4.5.2

I am trying to upgrade to .NET 4.5.2 on Windows 8.1. When I run the the installer(NDP452-KB2901907-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe), it is opening the maintenance dialog and asking me to "Repair or Remove" .NET 4.5.2 although I do not have it installed. Choosing repair, it says repair successful but does not seem like it installed it. Choosing remove tells me that it cannot be uninstalled and must be uninstalled from Control Panel(I cannot find it in Control Panel). Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image: Maintenance dialog]

[image: Control Panel]

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software tech support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 8.1 ships with .NET Framework 4.5.2. Of course that won't list with normal programs but you can check installed Windows component list.

Update: There is [an even easier way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed#net_d) to tell which version is installed.